# Searching for something in Database - SELECT - Need to search in 2 tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

[image]

As you can see in the print screen above, I am wondering, if it is possible to check if there is one thing in two tables at once. Without making 2 queries. I need to look, if "fajne-to-jest" is in table1 or table2. I'm doing it in 2 queries... but question is, is it possible to check this information using one query? Mabye something else? Most efficent way? The best way?

Comment: So you want to know if it is in one of the tables, no matter if it is in 1, 2 or in both? If it should be like in you picturem you can also do this with a query.

Comment: This information can be only in one table, this "url". Not in both. And in "url" column

Comment: But does it matter in which of the two tables it is?

Comment: Yes, and I look for this, in which table it is

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `exists` in the `select`:

```
select (exists (select 1 from table1 where url = 'fajne-to-jest')) as in_table1,
       (exists (select 1 from table2 where url = 'fajne-to-jest')) as in_table2;
```

Comment: Amazing. Thank you :D.

Comment: Is it possible to in addition take all single row containg this `url = 'fajne-to-jest'`  ? In this example to have result like this: `http://i.imgur.com/JG12hYs.png`

Comment: @AdriannoBarello . . . I think you should ask another question with sample data and desired results.

Comment: It would be allmost the same question, but with simple change, to something like this: `http://i.imgur.com/ZpP8h1G.png`

Comment: Please answer me to this one :) <3

Comment: @AdriannoBarello . . . Questions should be asked as questions and not in comments.

Answer (score 1):

Try UNION ALL to fetch data to two different tables

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE url = 'fajne-to-jest'
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE url = 'fajne-to-jest'
```

Comment: Doesn't work.
`"#1222 - The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns"` Table1 and Table2 looks a little bit different than on this print screen I gave. I gave tables without some columns. But column "url" matches in both tables

Answer (score 1):

Please try the below script:

```
DECLARE @SearchStr nvarchar(100)

SET @SearchStr  = '%test%'

DECLARE @Results TABLE( TableName nvarchar(256), ColumnName nvarchar(370), ColumnValue nvarchar(3630))

SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @TableName nvarchar(256), @ColumnName nvarchar(128), @SearchStr2 nvarchar(110)
SET  @TableName = ''
SET @SearchStr2 = QUOTENAME('%' + @SearchStr + '%','''')

WHILE @TableName IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    SET @ColumnName = ''
    SET @TableName = 
    (
        SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME))
        FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
        WHERE       TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
            AND QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME) > @TableName
            AND OBJECTPROPERTY(
                    OBJECT_ID(
                        QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME)
                         ), 'IsMSShipped'
                           ) = 0
    )

    WHILE (@TableName IS NOT NULL) AND (@ColumnName IS NOT NULL)
    BEGIN
        SET @ColumnName =
        (
            SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME))
            FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
            WHERE       TABLE_SCHEMA    = PARSENAME(@TableName, 2)
                AND TABLE_NAME  = PARSENAME(@TableName, 1)
                AND DATA_TYPE IN ('char', 'varchar', 'nchar', 'nvarchar')
                AND QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) > @ColumnName
        )

        IF @ColumnName IS NOT NULL
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO @Results
            EXEC
            (
                'SELECT DISTINCT ''' + @TableName + ''',''' + @ColumnName + ''', LEFT(' + @ColumnName + ', 3630) 
                FROM ' + @TableName + ' (NOLOCK) ' +
                ' WHERE ' + @ColumnName + ' LIKE ' + @SearchStr2
            )
        END
    END 
END

SELECT  TableName, ColumnName, ColumnValue 
FROM @Results
```

Put your search string in "@SearchStr".
I got this from this portal itself.